# tangent plane and tangent space coincide

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be a smooth function. Suppose $f^{-1}(0)$ is a regular level set of $\mathbb{R}^3$. If $X_p\in T_p\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $X_pf=0$ show that for any $h\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ such that $h|_{f^{-1}(0)}=0$  we have $X_ph=0$. In particular I am trying to show that $T_pf^{-1}(0)$ coincides with the tangent plane about $p$.

I was able to prove the backwards direction. May someone suggest a way to tackle this direction? (preferred without curves)

Comment: What is $T_p$??

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Tangent space. Isn't that common notation?

Comment: Thanks.  But to answer your question:  Not always.  It could mean other things as well.  All is clear now.

Comment: I think that the $T_p$ notation for the tangent space is likely the most common notation for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's because of the definition of regular value (or regular level set). Let $\phi$ be a local parametrization of $f^{-1}(0)$ in a neighborhood of $p$ with $\phi(0)=p$. Then $T_pf^{-1}(0) = \text{im}(d\phi_0)$ is a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

Now we have $h\circ\phi = 0$ (since $h\big|_{f^{-1}(0)} = 0$). By the chain rule,
$$dh_p\circ d\phi_0 = 0,$$
which means that $dh_p\big|_{T_pf^{-1}(0)} = 0$, as you asked.